# How to rejoin lines in a file that have control ^M in a text field

Tags: awk, sed

I am exporting data from 100's of UDB tables into .csv files. However I am hitting an issue using the exported data since some tables contain user text with control characters that are breaking the lines into new lines. Is there a way using sed or awk to remove ^M and rejoin only the lines impacted with ^M . I could clean this on output but I have so many tables that I was hoping to avoid checking there since majority of records are fine.

#### Example of broken Lines that need to become a single line

```
"91","2007-12-06-15.52.38.664462","C","The difference blah blah, is that blah blah, but blah blah ^M
","49 ","2007-12-06-14.52.41.000000","
"91","2007-12-06-15.52.38.664462","C","Pre  hard close^M
","N546 ","2015-06-16-14.23.26.000000","        "," "
```

There should be two lines there, but it is split over 4 because of the ^M characters.

Comment: Do the fields end with CRLF, so the data contains both CR and LF?  Do you want to remove the CR, the LF, or both?  Is there ever a significant (to be preserved) CR in the data?  (It's fairly clear there are going to be lots of significant LF (newlines, NL, `'\n'`) characters that must be preserved, as well perhaps as some that must be eliminated — depending on the answers to the first questions in this comment.)

Comment: Your 2nd line of input ends with a single `"` - what are we supposed to do with that?.

Comment: Also, do you ever have `^M` (and newline) followed by more running text, or is it always and only at the end of a quote-enclosed field?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Without your code, and an explanation of how it works, we are only guessing as to whether our interpretation of your problem description is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/\r$/{s///;N;s/\n//}' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: And `sed $'/\r$/{;s///;N;s/\\n/ /;}'` as a bash work-around if you are using a non-GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate answer to your question is most likely "No, you can't do this reliably the way you want".

That's because what you want is to interpret your data as actual CSV, rather than just rejoin lines. A `^M` character is a perfectly valid character given the format of your data.

```
foo,"bar","two
words",baz
```

Whether there's a `^M` or `^J` at the end of the first "line", the point is that these two "lines" represent a single record, the third field of which includes a line break.

Consider also the following record:

```
foo,bar,"one,two",baz
```

There are four fields, and the third one contains a comma. This is perfectly valid in comma-quote-delimited files. And awk (including gawk) does not understand this data format.

If you *really* want to join these lines, you might employ one of a number of strategies. One of my favourites is to look at the field count.

```
$ printf $'foo,bar,"one\r\ntwo",baz\n' | hexdump -c
0000000   f   o   o   ,   b   a   r   ,   "   o   n   e  \r  \n   t   w
0000010   o   "   ,   b   a   z  \n
0000017
$ printf $'foo,bar,"one\r\ntwo",baz\n' | awk -F, 'NF<4 { a=$0; getline b; $0=a b } {sub(/[^[:print:]]+/," ")} 1'
foo,bar,"one two",baz
```

Rather than detecting just the newline character, this tells awk to convert ANY string of non-printable characters into a single space.

It still doesn't help with quoted strings that embed a comma, of course. For that, you should consider switching to a solution in another language. A quick Google search found me [an option in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl).

Comment: I agree with your comments above that you can not to this reliably. The more I started to work with the various tables that contained text fields the more I realized that I would have no choice but to address the problem directly on the database by removing the Carriage return / LineFeed chars using the UDB replace function. Thanks for your advice.